# [Python3]How to plot 55 columns using seaborn/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

thanks in advance.

I wonder how to use the Seaborn + Matplotlib combination to make a beautiful bar chart.
Here is the sample dataset that I have:

```
         2015-01 2015-02 2015-03 2015-04 2015-05
negative   28      13       12     33      7  
positive   78      20       19     3       55  
neutral    17      5        45     24      9
```

And I want the bar chart to look like this [click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWZq7.png), this is the chart I used excel to create, but I wonder how to use python to do the same thing? Or similar things?

Comment: a quick google search can lead you to many solutions to this. Try this link... https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/barchart.html

Comment: @Elainayg: Does this help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe is Pandas DataFrame, you can do:

```
df.T.plot.bar(width=0.8, edgecolor='w', linewidth=3)
```

which gives you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Data

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
2015-01 2015-02 2015-03 2015-04 2015-05
negative 28 13 12 33 7
positive 78 20 19 3 55
neutral 17 5 45 24 9
"""), sep=" ", engine="python")

ndf = df.stack().reset_index()

ndf.columns = ['Emotion','Date','Count']
```

Seaborn

```
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.barplot(x="Date", hue="Emotion", y="Count", data=ndf)
```

[image]

Comment: @Elainayg: Great to have helped you! If you want you can vote / accept the answer.